# Does it make sense to reduce calls to send on a socket?

Tags: c, sockets

Currently working with sockets, I am wondering whether it makes sense to reduce the amount of calls to `send` for performance.

As far as I understood, there is a send buffer and the data is not dispatched immediately (?), but then I am wondering how long the kernel waits before actually sending the data and how much overhead would be caused by it if I call send multiple times instead of once?

Comment: Not really. The Nagle algorithm already takes care of it.

Comment: it makes sense to call `send` when you want to send something. `send` should not depend on performance IMO

Comment: @user207421 Thanks, I will investigate the Nagle algorithm

Comment: I'm puzzled whether you're using TCP or UDP.  If you're using TCP, as others have suggested, it barely matters when you call `send` -- although for TCP, you might as well call `write`.  If you're using UDP or some other packet-oriented protocol, on the other hand, it matters a great deal when you call `send`, because you're directly controllong packet boundaries, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For TCP, there is a send buffer controlled by the [Nagle algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) (and its interaction with [delayed acks](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_delayed_acknowledgment) from the receiver).

There isn't equivalent delay/buffering mechanism for UDP.

You haven't said which protocol you're using, but if it is TCP you probably don't need to do anything. For latency-sensitive code it can still be worth buffering writes just to avoid the syscall overhead, but I suppose you'd already know if that was your situation.